# need help for this F# code from Expert F# chapter 13

Tags: .net, asynchronous, f#

IEvent are missing, need help to make over this code.. I don't understand how to make trigger Event

```
// ----------------------------
// Listing 13-3.

open System
open System.Threading
open System.ComponentModel
open System.Windows.Forms

/// An IterativeBackgroudWorker follows the BackgroundWorker design pattern
/// but instead of running an arbitrary computation it iterates a function
/// a fixed number of times and reports intermediate and final results.
/// The worker is paramaterized by its internal state type.
///
/// Percentage progress is based on the iteration number. Cancellation checks
/// are made at each iteration. Implemented via an internal BackgroundWorker.
type IterativeBackgroundWorker<'a>(oneStep:('a -> 'a),
                                   initialState:'a,
                                   numIterations:int) =

    let worker =
        new BackgroundWorker(WorkerReportsProgress=true,
                             WorkerSupportsCancellation=true)

    // The constructor captures the synchronization context. This allows us to post
    // messages back to the GUI thread where the BackgroundWorker was created.
    let syncContext = SynchronizationContext.Current
    do if syncContext = null then failwith "no synchronization context found"

    // Create the events that we will later trigger
    let triggerStarted,  started   = IEvent.create()
    let triggerCompleted,completed = IEvent.create()
    let triggerError    ,error     = IEvent.create()
    let triggerCancelled,cancelled = IEvent.create()
    let triggerProgress ,progress  = IEvent.create()

    do worker.DoWork.Add(fun args ->
        syncContext.Post(SendOrPostCallback(fun _ -> triggerStarted(DateTime.Now)),
                         state=null)

        // This recursive function represents the computation loop.
        // It runs at "maximum speed", i.e. is an active rather than
        // a reactive process, and can only be controlled by a
        // cancellation signal.
        let rec iterate state i =
            // At the end of the compuation terminate the recursive loop
            if worker.CancellationPending then
               args.Cancel <- true
            elif i < numIterations then
                // Compute the next result
                let state' = oneStep state

                // Report the percentage compuation and the internal state
                let percent = int ((float (i+1)/float numIterations) * 100.0)
                do worker.ReportProgress(percent, box state);

                // Compute the next result
                iterate state' (i+1)
            else
                args.Result <- box state

        iterate initialState 0)

    do worker.RunWorkerCompleted.Add(fun args ->
        if args.Cancelled       then triggerCancelled()
        elif args.Error <> null then triggerError args.Error
        else triggerCompleted (args.Result :?> 'a))

    do worker.ProgressChanged.Add(fun args ->
        triggerProgress (args.ProgressPercentage,(args.UserState :?> 'a)))

    member x.WorkerCompleted  = completed
    member x.WorkerCancelled  = cancelled
    member x.WorkerError      = error
    member x.ProgressChanged  = progress

    // Delegate the remaining members to the underlying worker
    member x.RunWorkerAsync()    = worker.RunWorkerAsync()
    member x.CancelAsync()       = worker.CancelAsync()

    /// The Started event gets raised when the worker starts. It is
    /// raised on the GUI thread (i.e. in the synchronization context of
    /// the thread where the worker object was created).
    // It has type IEvent<DateTime>
    member x.Started             = started

let fibOneStep (fibPrevPrev:bigint,fibPrev) = (fibPrev, fibPrevPrev+fibPrev)

// ----------------------------

let worker = new IterativeBackgroundWorker<_>( fibOneStep,(1I,1I),100)

worker.WorkerCompleted.Add(fun result ->
      MessageBox.Show(sprintf "Result = %A" result) |> ignore)

worker.ProgressChanged.Add(fun (percentage, state) ->
    printfn "%d%% complete, state = %A" percentage state)

worker.RunWorkerAsync()

// ----------------------------
```

Just need clue how to make a new event that would be trigger later. But if someone want help to make over the code then it would be a big Thanks :D

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd233189.aspx

Answer (score 1):

From the docs:

```
open System.Collections.Generic

type MyClassWithCLIEvent() =

    let event1 = new Event<_>()

    [<CLIEvent>]
    member this.Event1 = event1.Publish

    member this.TestEvent(arg) =
        event1.Trigger(this, arg)

let classWithEvent = new MyClassWithCLIEvent()
classWithEvent.Event1.Add(fun (sender, arg) -> 
        printfn "Event1 occurred! Object data: %s" arg)

classWithEvent.TestEvent("Hello World!")
```

Answer (score 1):

The code posted by Daniel should give you the answer. Just to link that to the code from the (first version) of the Expert F# book, the changes are:

- The `IEvent.create()` function has been replaced by a type, so you'll use `new Event<_>()`
- The first element of the returned tuple (trigger function) is `Trigger` member of the object
- The second element of the tuple (`IEvent` value) is the `Publish` member of the object
- If you use `CLIEvent` attribute, the event will be compiled as .NET event (otherwise it will be just a property of the type `IEvent`)

I believe that these are the only breaking changes in the API for working with events. There is also a new module `Observable` that contains the same functions as `Event` (e.g. `Event.map`) and it is generally better to use the observable implementation (it is more standard and avoids potential memory leaks).